# Why didn't Norman hit back?

Tags: plot-explanation, bates-motel

I remember I was watching *[Bates Motel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bates_Motel_(TV_series))* and at school Norman got beat up by this bully in one episode but he didn't defend himself even though the bully was even smaller than him he still didn't hit back, why?